# Does English have an equivalent word for alimungawan?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

It's the short semiconscious or confused state after sleep. Very much like a hypnic jerk but you don't go back to sleep. Like waking up very early in the morning but you slept late your body is not ready to get up. Or being roused from sleep by an earthquake your body doesn't know how to react. You either get out of bed after this state or it may be followed by a short glassy-eyed idle moment.

Comment: I know you requested a single word, but would you accept a 2-word phrase? [Sleep inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_inertia) sounds like what you're looking for. If so, I'll post it as answer.

Comment: @Lawrence - it is a good suggestion, post an answer.

Comment: What is the source language of 'alimungawan'? There might very well be already accepted translations.

Comment: @Mitch Found this: http://translate.sandayong.com/cebuano/english/alimungawan

Comment: @Gandalf the comments explain a lot.

Comment: @Mitch What I was referring to was the language. It's Cebuano, from the Philippines.

Comment: @gandalf I was being funny. That site has a comment thread discussing the phrase (I think) but it's mostly cebuano (I'm guessing) and google translate doesn't really do much for it.

Answer (score 33):

I would call this being ***[groggy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/groggy)***:

> not able to think or move normally because of being tired, sick, etc.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Or grogginess, in the event that a noun is needed.

Answer (score 19):

**Hypnagogia** is a fancy term for *half-awake* or *half-asleep*. Personally, I prefer the latter two. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnagogia) article says:

> However, **hypnagogia** is also regularly employed in a more general sense that covers both falling asleep and waking up […] Threshold consciousness (commonly called "half-asleep" or "half-awake", or "mind awake body asleep") describes the same mental state of **someone who is moving towards sleep or wakefulness, but has not yet completed the transition.** Such transitions are usually brief, but can be extended by sleep disturbance or deliberate induction, for example during meditation

Comment: I had a look at this also, as well as the more waking-specific term [hypnopompic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnopompic), but didn't get the impression that the word addressed the confusion and lack of motor control that the OP was looking for.

Comment: I think Hypnopompic is technically correct: "Depressed frontal lobe function in the first few minutes after waking ... causes slowed reaction time and impaired short-term memory" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnopompic . However not many people will know what you're talking about!

Answer (score 9):

This is called **sleep inertia**.

> Sleep inertia is a physiological state characterised by a decline in motor dexterity and a subjective feeling of grogginess immediately following an abrupt awakening.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_inertia)

Comment: Curiously, by the definition of inertia the expression "sleep inertia" should also apply to insomnia.

Comment: @ANeves That might be better termed the inertia of *being awake* :) .

Answer (score 6):

There is the term "sleep drunk":

> having trouble coming to full wakefulness after sleep, accompanied by
>   intense confusion and disorientation, and even sometimes violent
>   reactions and amnesia

http://time.com/3170331/1-in-7-people-suffer-from-sleep-drunkenness/

Answer (score 5):

I would call this being [drowsy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drowsy):

> drowsy (ˈdraʊzɪ)
>      adj, drowsier or drowsiest
>
> 1. (Physiology) heavy with sleepiness; sleepy
> 2. inducing sleep; soporific
> 3. sluggish or lethargic; dull

Comment: I tend to associate "drowsy" more with falling asleep when you want to stay awake, rather than being half-asleep while you're waking up.

Comment: Like Mason, I have only ever seen "drowsy" used in American English to mean close to falling asleep. I suppose one could say that a person is "still drowsy" after waking up, but I've never seen that usage.

Answer (score -3):

It's a metaphor, but you could try [fug](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fug)

It literally means a smoky atmosphere, but it can be used to mean that kind of disorientation, when you're not yet fully aware of your surroundings.

Comment: That word is extremely rare. I've *never* seen it used in casual writing; most readers would be likely to think it was a typo for "fog".

Comment: It may be  part of a regional dialect, I use it a lot in that context and people understand me.